# Why is this regexp in .htaccess not matching?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following line:

```
RewriteRule ^page.php?var1=([0-9]+)&var2=(.*)&var3=(.*)$ index.php?module=page&var1=$1
```

When I visit the directory with this url: page.php?var1=24&var2=346adf&var3=asdf

It doesnt do the regexp. Anyone having a clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically your rule is incorrect. Reason: You can only match REQUEST_URI using `RewriteRule` but cannot match QUERY String in there.

Change your code to this to make it correct:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^var1=([0-9]+)&var2=[^&]*&var3=.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^page\.php/?$ index.php?module=page&var1=%1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Should ^page\.php/?$ be ^page\.php\?$

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I notice is that the ? should probably be escaped.

Answer (score 1):

Besides missing escapes, query string (the stuff after `?`) is not part of the `RewriteRule` matching.
You have to use an additional `RewriteCond` if you want to match on the query string.
For example:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^foo=([^&]+)&bar$
RewriteRule ^page\.php$ otherpage.php?x=%1 [QSA]
```

I wouldn't recommend this tho. You are better off parsing the query string in your scripts.